# Сокращенное название организации

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, АНО ВО "Межрегиональный открытый социаьный институт", сокращение МОСИ нужно писать в кавычках? АНО ВО "МОСИ"? 
И с какой буквы писать "автономный" - с прописной или строчной?

Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Каждая организация юридическое лицо при создании принимает Устав - один из основополагающих документов, регламентирующих деятельность организации.

В Уставе фиксируется наименование организации. Также, организация может зафиксировать сокращённое (краткое) наименование организации. Поэтому возможны два случая:

- Организация имеет обязательное наименование (т.н. "полное") и сокращённое
- Организация имеет наименование и в Уставе не зафиксировано сокращённое

Сокращённое наименование, кстати, не всегда так уж и очевидно, особенно для каких-либо районных администраций.

При подготовке каких-либо официальных документов рекомендуется использовать данные, зафиксированные в Уставе.  Как правило, организации, находящиеся в договорных отношениях обмениваются своими реквизитами, включая расчётные счета, ИНН/КПП, ОГРН и проч.

Как правило, при подготовке Устава следуют правилам русского языка, выше их хорошо описал @Morkovkin. Поэтому, если у вас на руках нет реквизитов (такое бывает, когда организации только начинают вести переписку) можете ориентироваться на общие правила.

Answer (score 0):

В кавычках сокращения обычно не пишутся. 
По поводу заглавной буквы: если это первое слово официального названия (судя по вашим сокращения, это так и есть), то оно всегда с заглавной. Если слово не первое, то причин для заглавной с точки зрения орфографии нет никаких, но тут часто приходится руководствоваться уставным названием, а не правилами орфографии.

Comment: Странный какой-то институт... Нельзя ли его вообще сократить, вместе с бюджетом и творческим коллективом?